# Elixir Phoenix date_select have last 10 years in year select

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

Can anyone tell how to make it so that the `date_select` helper in Phoenix will show current year as the max year and show last 10 years as an option to choose.
Currently its showing me years from 2010 to 2020. Since this is a date of birth field it cannot be in future.

Answer (score 4):

There is an example for this in [`phoenix_html`'s documentation](http://hexdocs.pm/phoenix_html/Phoenix.HTML.Form.html#datetime_select/3):

```
datetime_select form, :born_at, year: [options: 1900..2100]
```

Comment: Thanks @michalmuskala, can we do year: `[options: 1900..DateTime.current_year]` ?

Comment: Yes, it's perfectly possible. You could for instance leverage Ecto, and use `Ecto.Date.utc.year`. You could also access the year directly from `:calendar.universal_time`.